# Why does the application pool automatically stop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, application-pool

I'm doing performance testing for my MVC internet application using IIS 7.0

Sometimes the application pool stops and I get an error saying "service unavailable" in my browser. I then have to restart the pool.

Why is the pool automatically stopped, and how can I solve this problem?

**update**
And my log file has : "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error."

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475214/net-mvc-4-project-fails-with-event-log-error-the-module-dll-c-windows-system3

Answer (score 19):

The application pool stops when it can't recover from an error/crash. Look at the Event Viewer under *Windows Logs > Application* to see the exception(s) that caused the crash. The **Source** column will mention something like *ASP.NET 4.0.30319.0*

[image: screenshot of event viewer]

Comment: my log file has : "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error."

Comment: You should probably open a follow-up question for that. Some quick searches indicate that this could be a faulty installation or configuration within the .NET Framework or IIS.

Comment: More details? I was unable to find this log.

Comment: @DanielGrover I've added a screenshot to help you locate the log message.

Comment: Thanks! I found it now!

Answer (score 19):

Well, I encounter also this problem and this is what I do.

1) Open IIS.

2) Right click on your Application-Pool for the web application and select "Advanced Settings".

3) Set "Rapid-Fail Protection" -> "Enabled" to False.

If this is true, the Application pool is shut down if there are a specified number of worker process crashes within a specified time period. By default, an application pool is shutdown if there are 5 crashes within a 5 minutes interval.

I read the answer in this link 
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22885/application-pool-is-auto-stopped-when-browse-web-application-in-iis7]

hope that this will give help to others.

Comment: Had the same issue, long term solution for me, after seeing page that was issue from Stijn's suggestion is to fix bug. Short term solution, going to try this pool setting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i had a similar problem, just with another module.

After looking to the event log, check if the needed module is present in the system32\inetsrv folder. If it is absent then delete/comment the appropriate line in the system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config in the globalModules section. Perhaps you will have to delete some modules (that also won't be found and pointed by event viewer) from your IIS application pool.

This helped for me, before that i had tried a lot of things including numerous reinstallations of IIS and .NET Framework.