# .Net MVC 4 Project fails with Event Log Error "The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll failed to load. The data is the error."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is not a DotNetCore project (it's an MVC 4 project) and the app pool is properly configured to use dotnet CLR v4, yet after updating to a new version of Windows 10 (be it an insider build, or the new Anniversary Update), starting the app fails and the event log shows the following error:

The Module DLL C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\aspnetcore.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

I don't have any need for aspnetcore.dll yet. And removing references to the DLL for the site in IIS doesn't solve the problem. Any Tips?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's the easiest solution:

1. Search Cortana for `Programs and Features` to open the legacy Control Panel's installed applications list.
2. Find and click the entry for `Microsfot .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling ...`

   - *My version is "Preview 2"... though if they don't fix this, you may have a newer version*
3. Click Change.
4. Click Repair.

The source of this problem seems to be the build upgrade process for Windows 10, where it re-installs IIS... while it copies over all the site settings to the new applicationHost.config, it seems to break any non-standard modules you previously had installed. For example, this same problem also affects the URL Rewrite 2 module (which is also fixed by running a repair).

Hopefully the team at Microsoft who works on maintaining the IIS config between build updates will get a chance to fix this (they're tracking this bug on github [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1583)). Until then, you have to do this repair after installing any new Windows builds.

**UPDATE:** This bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1583#issuecomment-271383889) in Windows 10 Insider Build 15002, and will be released as part of the Windows 10 Creators Update on April 11, 2017. So, once you've solved this by following the steps above, you shouldn't run into it again with the next major Windows 10 update.

Comment: How did you uninstall them? The Uninstall button in Extensions and Updates is greyed out and it's not listing them if I go to Programs and Features and select modify on Visual Studio

Comment: @BTC Where did you find the .NET Core option in the VS installer? I can't seem to find it...

Comment: @silkfire I updated the answer to make it more clear. Look in "Programs and Features". A repair will work just fine without having to do a complete uninstall.

Comment: just had this occur after this week's windows 10 version 1607 update

Comment: It also appears to break URL Rewrite 2.0 in the same way. Reinstalling should fix it. (IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 Module in programs and features)

Comment: @Sippy yes it does, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Spot on - had to repair both the tooling and rewrite modules - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Download the DotNetCore.1.0.0.RC2-SDK.Preview1-x64.exe, execute and uninstall. After, go to Programs and Features e Repair the Microsoft.NET Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 1. Work for me.

Comment: Just repairing "Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.0 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2" worked for me. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue. As a workaround, I marked **Enable 32-Bit Application** as **false** in application pool.

For more details, please check at below link
https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1583

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved after copy aspnetcore.dll 
From:
C:\Windows.old\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv 
Into:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv